# How to use results from a subquery in an "IN" clause with rethinkDB REQL

Tags: rethinkdb

So I'm not sure if this would b econsidered an inner join or a merge in ReQL.  What I want to do is watch for changes in online status of people I'm following.

So the first query works if I pass in the people I'm following via arguments:

```
r.table("users")
  .getAll(r.args(['mike','foo']), {index: "name"})
  .pluck('name', 'online')
  .changes();
```

However, I want to just pass in my username and let it fetch the following list dynamically - I would normally use a join or a subquery in SQL, but how would I do this in ReQL?  I tried using a lambda I didn't get the right syntax.

```
r.table("users")
  .getAll(r.args(lambda following {
       r.table('users').get('mike').pluck('following')
     }), 
     {index: "name"})
  .pluck('name', 'online')
  .changes();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write `.getAll(r.args(r.table('users').get('mike')('following')), {index: 'name'})`, but subscribing to changes on that might not do what you think it does -- it will get the users `mike` is following at the time the changefeed starts, and subscribe to changes on them, but if `mike` starts following a new user that user won't be automatically added to the feed.

Comment: oh, yeah, that would not be what I want... is there a way to have it dynamically update the following subcription when mike starts following a new user?

Comment: also, the part where you access the property `.get('mike')('following')` is that documented somewhere? I would have assumed that I would have had to use dot notation or `pluck` to project a property

Comment: The easiest way to do that would be to flip the relationship: instead of `mike` having a set of users he's following, give each user a set of people following them.  Then you could create a multi-index on it: `r.table('users').indexCreate('followers', {multi: true})` and write `r.table('users').getAll('mike', {index: 'followers'}).changes()`.  That will handle following and unfollowing correctly (adding a new follower will look like an insert, removing a follower will look like a delete).

Comment: The `()` notation is documented at https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/bracket/ .

Comment: ignore my comment about nested fields - I see that in the documentation now https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/nested-fields/javascript/

Comment: to add one more wrinkle, if I want to get real-time query of current rooms of users I'm following, do I add an eqJoin to the query to join on rooms.participants?  I wouldn't be able to use the similar technique of search by my username in the rooms table since participants would be the following username rather than the usernames of followers.  Assuming that the rooms collection has a participants array property.

Comment: I would reverse it again: instead of giving the room a `participants` array, give the users a `rooms` array that says what rooms they're in and create a multi-index on it.  That way when they enter or leave a room it will show up as a change to the user and you'll receive it in your changefeed like normal.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to get a list of all rooms with a flag on rooms that are occupied by people I'm following.  Using the reversed method I think would get me a list of all users I'm following with rooms they are in but not the left join of all the rooms - if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: The easiest way to do that would be to put a `map` after the changefeed and inside the map to retrieve rooms from the rooms table based on the `setDifference` of the rooms the user is subscribed to.

Comment: just tested the solution outlined in the answer in data explorer and I couldn't get it to pick up changes to new follows and unfollows.  It picked up changes to the online status of the existing follow list but when I added or removed followers, it did not pick up the changes in the changefeed , i.e. `r.table('users').getAll('mike', {index: 'followers'}).pluck('name', 'online').changes({includeInitial:true});` did not pick up changes from `r.table('users').get('foo').update({followers:r.row('followers').setDifference(['mike'])})`

Comment: so it looks like using `pluck()` for some reason doesn't allow for me to see the inserts and deletes.  Without pluck it works fine.  I don't necessarily need the full user data returned on the changefeeds.  Why doesn't it work with pluck?  Is there another way I should be limiting the data being returned?

Comment: I could use the inverse selection by using `.without('password', 'phone')` etc.. but that seems like a fragile way of doing it since anytime I have new properties I would have to updat that.